# MySQL IF return multiple values?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

How can I return multiple values from an IF statement in MySQL? Embedding the IF into the query is not an option.

```
SET @values = IF(@year = 2014, (2, 3, 4), 1); # either (2, 3, 4) OR 1
SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE `column` IN (@values);
```

> Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

One solution would be to use quotation marks and store that value to a variable, but it does not work with the IN command, it needs raw numbers:

```
SELECT IF (24 IN ("23,24,25"), TRUE, FALSE) AS `does-it-contain`;
```

> FALSE

Comment: There isn't a simple, elegant way to do what you want.  `find_in_set()` is perhaps the simplest, but it does not have the best performance.  Dynamic SQL is the fastest method, but it is not elegant.

Comment: A variable can only hold one value. SQL doesn't have arrays or lists as values.

Comment: *"Embedding the IF into the query is not an option."*  Why not?  What about `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE (@year = 2014 AND c1 IN (2,3,4)) OR (@year != 2014 AND c1 IN (1))`?  The condition that is impossible should be optimized away automatically, making this style just as efficient.

Comment: Because this is a simplified example, the real query joins 6 tables with several hundred thousand rows and embedding the IFs would slow it down considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this in a procedure (either a MySQL stored procedure or from a client programming language) you can use a temporary table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_values (value INT, PRIMARY KEY value);
IF @year = 2014
THEN INSERT INTO temp_values VALUES (2), (3), (4);
ELSE INSERT INTO temp_values VALUES (1);
END IF;
SELECT w.* FROM wherever AS w
JOIN temp_values AS v ON v.column = v.value;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using temporary table because it takes up a lot of memory and retrieval time will also increase. Also, will it work when multiple users are trying to access the data at a point of time?

Comment: Temporary tables are private to each database connection, so you can do it with multiple users running at the same time. If I could have thought of a way to do it without a table, I would have posted that. You could use `ENGINE=MEMORY` for the table, to reduce the retrieval time. If it's just a small number of values like this, it won't take up lots of memory.